The "providers" array is not present in laravel's config/app.php
I want to register the 'authserviceprovider' provider in the 'provider' array in config/app.php, but the 'provider' array is not in that file, is there something wrong with my installation, or my laravel version?, I'm using laravel 10 and php 8.2.12
here is my config.app.php file
Previously on my project, I wanted to create an SSO server, so I installed the Auth and Passport packages, help me solve this problem
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application, which will be used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | other UI elements where an application name needs to be displayed.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services the application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => (bool) env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | the application so that it's available within Artisan commands.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. The timezone
    | is set to "UTC" by default as it is suitable for most use cases.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE', 'UTC'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by Laravel's translation / localization methods. This option can be
    | set to any locale for which you plan to have translation strings.
    |
    */

    'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),

    'fallback_locale' => env('APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE', 'en'),

    'faker_locale' => env('APP_FAKER_LOCALE', 'en_US'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is utilized by Laravel's encryption services and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string to ensure that all encrypted values
    | are secure. You should do this prior to deploying the application.
    |
    */

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'previous_keys' => [
        ...array_filter(
            explode(',', env('APP_PREVIOUS_KEYS', ''))
        ),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Maintenance Mode Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These configuration options determine the driver used to determine and
    | manage Laravel's "maintenance mode" status. The "cache" driver will
    | allow maintenance mode to be controlled across multiple machines.
    |
    | Supported drivers: "file", "cache"
    |
    */

    'maintenance' => [
        'driver' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_DRIVER', 'file'),
        'store' => env('APP_MAINTENANCE_STORE', 'database'),
    ],


];


I want the next time I create my Laravel project that I have that array and the authserviceprovider too. or in this project there is a way to provide the array

As per your code,It seems like you are using Laravel 11, not Laravel 10.

In Laravel 11,All service providers are registered in the
bootstrap/providers.php configuration file. This file returns an array
that contains the class names of your application's service providers.
When you invoke the make:provider Artisan command, Laravel will
automatically add the generated provider to the
bootstrap/providers.php file. However, if you have manually created
the provider class, you should manually add the provider class to the
array


if you have custom service providers then you can register it in bootstrap\providers.php
if you read release note
Service Providers

Instead of the default Laravel application structure containing five
service providers, Laravel 11 only includes a single
AppServiceProvider. The functionality of the previous service
providers has been incorporated into the bootstrap/app.php, is handled
automatically by the framework, or may be placed in your application's
AppServiceProvider.
For example, event discovery is now enabled by default, largely
eliminating the need for manual registration of events and their
listeners. However, if you do need to manually register events, you
may simply do so in the AppServiceProvider. Similarly, route model
bindings or authorization gates you may have previously registered in
the AuthServiceProvider may also be registered in the
AppServiceProvider.


wow that worked for me thanks for the help
